# Property 'limitTags' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AutocompleteProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Material UI and Lab Versions I am using

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.8.3",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.44",
```

[Link to component](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#limit-tags)

My Code

```
    <Autocomplete
     multiple
     limitTags={2}

     id="multiple-limit-tags"
     options={Audience}
     getOptionLabel={(option: any) => option.title}
     renderInput={(params) => (
     <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" placeholder="Select collaborator's audience" size="small" />
     )}
 />
```

This attribute is creating issue

```
limitTags={2}
```

Comment: Add the code here which gives that error

Comment: autocomplete is not in @material-ui/core, it's in @material-ui/lab

Comment: please check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`limitTags` feature is added in - `4.0.0-alpha.47` version

```
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.47",
```

[image]

You should update your npm packages and it should solve your problem.

Working exmaple for autocomplete with limit tags is here - https://codesandbox.io/s/s81k4

Comment: Glad to know it helped.Cheers